# Print array values based in sorting list and ascending order

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, multiple-conditions

Please your help. I have the array "values" that I want to sort by 2 conditions.

First condition: Using the sort list defined in array "sortlist".
Second condition: From smallest to largest.

With my current script I've been able to print the values in correct order for first condition (sort list), but I don't have an idea how to apply the second sorting condition (smallest to largest).

```
ruby -e'
values = [ "Ghu_1","Prw_1","Prw_3","Prw_5","Vep_3","Hom_2","Vep_1","Hom_1","Prw_2","Vep_2","Prw_4" ]
sortlist = [ "Hom","Vep","Ghu","Prw" ]

sortlist.each{ |s| 
 values.each{ |v| 
     puts v if v.include?(s)
 }
}'




Current Ouput  #  Desired output
   Hom_2       #      Hom_1
   Hom_1       #      Hom_2
   Vep_3       #      Vep_1
   Vep_1       #      Vep_2
   Vep_2       #      Vep_3
   Ghu_1       #      Ghu_1
   Prw_1       #      Prw_1
   Prw_3       #      Prw_2
   Prw_5       #      Prw_3
   Prw_2       #      Prw_4
   Prw_4       #      Prw_5
```

UPDATE

Thank Sebastian. Excellent.

It almost work since I noticed that if the characters after "_" are not numbers the second sort is not correct. For example below output is incorrect for values of Pwr_XXX

```
 ruby -e'
 values = [ "Ghu_Klca","Prw_Rkdg","Prw_Ceteu","Prw_Eriir","Vep_Msas23","Hom_Ttgr5","Vep_Qsccas","Hom_Ftjh","Prw_jpolq","Vep_Szbqh","Prw_Lmnajh" ]
 sortlist = [ "Hom","Vep","Ghu","Prw" ]

 puts sortlist.flat_map{ |s|
   values.select{ |v|
     v if v.include?(s)
   }.sort
 }'
```

2nd Update

I mean that the first sort is based on sortlist array. The second sort is ascending based in characters after "_". In this case the firt letter for Prw values are
C, E, j, L and R. But the current output is C, E, L, R and j. So, j is at the end and should be after L. I hope make sense.

```
Current output        Expected output
Hom_Ftjh          #      Hom_Ftjh 
Hom_Ttgr5         #      Hom_Ttgr5 
Vep_Msas23        #      Vep_Msas23 
Vep_Qsccas        #      Vep_Qsccas 
Vep_Szbqh         #      Vep_Szbqh 
Ghu_Klca          #      Ghu_Klca 
Prw_Ceteu         #      Prw_Ceteu 
Prw_Eriir         #      Prw_Eriir 
Prw_Lmnajh        #      Prw_jpolq 
Prw_Rkdg          #      Prw_Lmnajh 
Prw_jpolq         #      Prw_Rkdg
```

Comment: What do you mean with second sort is not correct? What's the expected output?

Comment: Please see my 2nd update. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, what you could do is to create an empty array, and then inside your `values.each` iteration, to push each element to your empty array if that element include the element from the `sortlist`

```
new_list = []
sortlist.each{ |s|
  values.each{ |v|
    new_list << v if v.include?(s)
  }
}
```

Then use `group_by` to group them by its first character:

```
p new_list.group_by{|e| e[0]}
# => {"H"=>["Hom_2", "Hom_1"], "V"=>["Vep_3", "Vep_1", "Vep_2"], "G"=>["Ghu_1"], "P"=>["Prw_1", "Prw_3", "Prw_5", "Prw_2", "Prw_4"]}
```

Then use `flat_map` to get a "plain" array with all your values, but inside the iteration sort each values for each key in the hash:

```
p new_list.group_by{|e| e[0]}.flat_map{|_,v| v.sort}
# => ["Hom_1", "Hom_2", "Vep_1", "Vep_2", "Vep_3", "Ghu_1", "Prw_1", "Prw_2", "Prw_3", "Prw_4", "Prw_5"]
```

Or a `flat_map`, `select` and `sort_by` combination (2nd update):

```
values = [ "Ghu_Klca","Prw_Rkdg","Prw_Ceteu","Prw_Eriir","Vep_Msas23","Hom_Ttgr5","Vep_Qsccas","Hom_Ftjh","Prw_jpolq","Vep_Szbqh","Prw_Lmnajh" ]
sortlist = [ "Hom","Vep","Ghu","Prw" ]

p sortlist.flat_map{ |s|
  values.select{ |v|
    v if v.include?(s)
  }.sort_by(&:downcase)
}
# => ["Hom_Ftjh", "Hom_Ttgr5", "Vep_Msas23", "Vep_Qsccas", "Vep_Szbqh", "Ghu_Klca", "Prw_Ceteu", "Prw_Eriir", "Prw_jpolq", "Prw_Lmnajh", "Prw_Rkdg"]
```

Use `sort_by(&:downcase)` to "ignore" case when sorting.

Comment: Just work exactly like I was looking for. Your 2nd update even sorts numeric values! Muchas Gracias Sebastián.

Answer (score 2):

```
values.sort_by { |val|
  front, back = val.split('_')
  [sortlist.index(front), back.downcase]
}
# => ["Hom_1", "Hom_2", "Vep_1", "Vep_2", "Vep_3", "Ghu_1", "Prw_1", "Prw_2", "Prw_3", "Prw_4", "Prw_5"]
# or
# => ["Hom_Ftjh", "Hom_Ttgr5", "Vep_Msas23", "Vep_Qsccas", "Vep_Szbqh", "Ghu_Klca", "Prw_Ceteu", "Prw_Eriir", "Prw_Lmnajh", "Prw_Rkdg", "Prw_jpolq"]
```

This works because arrays compare by comparing the first element, then comparing the next element if the previous is equal. Currently I'm comparing the `back` as if it were a string (`10` comes before `2`); if you want numeric ordering (`2` comes before `10`), use `back.to_i` or `back.to_f` (but that won't work with the second example).

Comment: Thanks Amadan for your explanation. Do you know how could be fixed the sorting within each group of similar values? I call it the second sort.

Comment: Based on your clarification, you want case-insensitive sort. This can be done by a `downcase` in the sorting criterion.  Answer changed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much Amadan. It works just fine your updated solution.